# Select between 2 dates in sqlite, using 2 columns

Tags: sqlite

I have an table RECORDS in `SQLITE` where it contains 2 columns `date` varchar, `time` varchar, where date column is in format `2017-01-20` and time format `15:43`

```
CREATE TABLE "RECORDS" (
  "date" VARCHAR,  /*2017-01-23*/
  "time" VARCHAR    /*14:00*/
  )
```

Is there a way to select all the records from the table Between `2017-01-23 05:00` AND `2017-01-24 02:00`

Here is the [sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/72f88/2)

I tried (

```
SELECT * RECORDS
WHERE date >= date('2017-01-23') AND date <= date('2017-01-24')
ORDER BY DATE,TIME
```

but I can't select also the 05:00 - 02:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following query should work, because comparisons against the date and time should work numerically given the formats you have (i.e. `yyyy-mm-dd` for dates, `hh:mm` for times).

```
SELECT *
FROM RECORDS
WHERE (date = '2017-01-23' AND time > '05:00') OR
      (date = '2017-01-24' AND time < '02:00')
```

This assumes that all entries in your `time` column have five characters in the format `hh:mm`.